# Deploy WordPress DB preserving comments

Tags: php, wordpress, deployment, phpmyadmin

I manage a Website developed with WordPress with a local MySql DB managed with phpMyAdmin. The production Website uses another DB in another server.

The DB contains all the website texts (as usual) and it's updated in the local version during the development.

Before the first release I used to replace the whole content of production DB with the development DB, but now the Website is online and Users wrote several comments that I would like to keep.

I need to write a small guide for people who will deploy new versions, to prevent overwrites of Comments written by users.

I wonder if it's enough to keep just wp_commentmeta and wp_comments tables?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: use a sync tool to upgrade your schema, mysqlworkbench comes with one

Comment: @DevZer0 Ok, but I wonder which tables I must keep untouched to be sure comments won't be erased. I'm not a Wordpress expert though.

Comment: well i would think you will need to keep `posts` along with comments, no point keeping comments if no `posts`. Best route for upgrading the production db with data is to sync.

Comment: @DevZer0 Yes you're right but in my Website users can only comment posts and not make new posts, that's why I mentioned only comments.